# ImportError: No module named bingsearch

Tags: python, import, module

I have a script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import bingsearch
bingsearch.API_KEY='Your-Api-Key-Here'
r = bingsearch.request("Python Software Foundation")
r.status_code
```

and also:

```
$which python
/usr/bin/python
```

But when I copy script into `bingsearch` directory that I downloaded it works..

Should I set path? how?

Why do I have this error? Could you possibly help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the import procedure that most programmers will need to care about is usually the first—locating the file to be imported (the “find it” part). Because you may need to tell Python where to look to find files to import, you need to know how to tap into its search path in order to extend it.

The Module Search Path Order

1. The home directory of the program
2. PYTHONPATH directories (if set)
3. Standard library directories
4. The contents of any .pth files (if present)
5. The site-packages home of third-party extensions

For editing PYTHONPATH please check [here](http://www.bdnyc.org/2012/09/17/editing-pythonpath-to-import-modules/)

Comment: Pardon, You are right but I don't know why in my case not work...What path I should append now?

Comment: @MortezaLSC: did you added ** bingsearch** module in PYTHONPATH ?

Comment: I do:  `sys.path.append("/dir/projects/workspace/bingsearch")`

Comment: Ok..It doesn't have `__init__.py`  correct..thank you